# Elite Dangerous key binding

Tags: elite-dangerous

I set a key ("V") to be Deploy Heatsink, but this does nothing at all when i press it.

I then noticed that the heatsink appears as a 'weapon' in the fire groups setup, so I set firegroup 2 to be Beam Laser Primary and Heatsink Secondary, but I can't switch to that firegroup, despite binding [ and ] to previous and next firegroup... what am I doing wrong?

I have a Mad Catz FLY 5 joystick which seems to work well on the default control presets for that joystick but no changes I make on the Beta seem to take effect.

Comment: Why the downvote? Helpful criticism would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: What version is this with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved - USER ERROR

I realised last night that this was down to me not clicking Apply after making my changes and pressing "ESC".  In my defence ESC does exit other screens in the game without abandoning changes so it might be useful to include a warning if there are unsaved changes on the keybinding change but I will suggest this on the dev forum.

Comment: I share your pain with the 'apply' button, even though I know it's there I still find myself having to go back and re-do a mapping change because I just pressed esc

Comment: Glad it's not just me! :-) I felt very stupid after figuring this one out

Comment: Update: there is now a warning before canceling without saving changes.